# onDestroy is getting called after onAdLoaded in CustomEventBanner

Tags: android, admob

I created a customevent and I noticed that the onDestroy in the customevent is getting called after onAdLoaded. This only happens when the banner refresh using the admob builtin refresh.
Anybody know something about this?

```
01-11 12:25:39.195: I/AdMediationCustomevent(8171): onAdLoaded
...
01-11 12:25:39.265: I/Ads(8171): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
...
01-11 12:25:39.330: I/AdMediationCustomevent(8171): onDestroy
...
01-11 12:25:39.330: I/Ads(8171): Ad finished loading.
01-11 12:25:39.330: I/AdBanner(8171): onAdLoaded
```

I don't call onDestroy. this is called somewere in the admob sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did some more research and found that actually the onDestroy is called on a different instance of the AdMediationCustomevent class (The previous one). So nothing to worry.

CLOSED